# How to split a string into fixed length rows?

Tags: python

I have a code that asks user to give lines with different amount of words in them, the next line is always given on another row.
I want to split the given text into user inputted lenght in different rows.

Right now I have a piece of code that splits the lines to wanted user inputted length, but since it counts the space (" ") as one "word",some lines start with space. How do i stop that from happening?

```
def chunkstring(string, length):
    return (string[0+i:length+i] for i in range(0, len(string), length))

def main():

    print("Enter text rows. Quit by entering an empty row.")
    msg = read_message()
    lines = (i.strip() for i in msg.splitlines())
    get_line = int(input("Enter the number of characters per line: "))
    for line in lines:
        for chunk in chunkstring(line, get_line):
            print(chunk)
``
```

Comment: You're chunking the lines by the number of characters they contain, not the number of words. What exactly is it that you want?

Comment: I want to chunk them to characters, not the words. Sorry if that was unclear!

Comment: In that case @Gamopo's suggestion will remove the any leading or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python strip to eliminate the remaining spaces, check [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp) or [this other one](https://www.journaldev.com/23763/python-remove-spaces-from-string)

So just print `chunk.strip()`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use *regular expressions*. Also, you don't need to do a `splitlines` before:

```py
import re

print("Enter text rows. Quit by entering an empty row.")
msg = read_message()
width = int(input("Enter the number of characters per line: "))

pat = re.compile(f" *.{{1,{width}}}")

chunks = pat.findall(msg)
for chunk in chunks:
    print(chunk)
```